# Deno import modules from private repo

Tags: github, authorization, repository, private, deno

I tried to import a module from my private repository (GitHub). Following the Deno [documentation](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.0/basics/modules/reloading_modules), I put `DENO_AUTH_TOKENS` env with my dev key `xxxxxx@raw.githubusercontent.com`.

I can load the main file module on my repo but all relative paths from this module fail to download (404, path is correct just not authorized I suppose).

Do you know how to fix load relative file from a module in a private repository?

I ran my process with the debug mode:

```
deno run -L debug main.ts
```

Output:

```
DEBUG RS - deno::auth_tokens:69 - Parsed 1 auth token(s).
```

so my auth is correctly parsed and I can load the first file but all relative files can't be loaded.

----- Edit
Ok my bad, i wanted to use my node module to deno but i forgot to rename all import with .ts at the end... i'm so stupid, sorry ;) .

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Did you (A) [generate](https://github.com/settings/tokens?type=beta) and use a personal access token for your GitHub account (with the appropriate scope of [`Contents: Read-only`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens?apiVersion=2022-11-28#contents)), or (B) use the one that is auto-generated and included in the URL (as the value of the `token` query parameter) when clicking the "Raw" link associated to a file?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286289/deno-import-private-repo#comment132859227_75286289) If B: that token is temporary and only valid for the specific file: using it for other files results in a 404.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the token is only needed to initially [cache](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.0/basics/modules/reloading_modules) the modules: after they are cached, the token is never needed again until cache eviction occurs (e.g. by manual deletion or using `--reload`).

Comment: Hello thanks for you reply. It's difficult to do an example for loading error. I generate a personnal token from github with the correct scope repository and reads contents access. I can import the first modules from my repo mod.ts but all import script in this file can't be loaded, 404 error. The url for each file are correct but i have a 404 so i suppose than my access is deny. I check my token with postman or curl with my token in header and target each file on my repo and it's fine a can see the content for each file.