# Deno import from private GitHub repo: Module not found

Tags: github, deno

I'm trying to import a .ts file from a private GitHub repo and I'm getting the error

```
error: Module not found "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<pathToTheFile>/index.d.ts".
```

I have a .env file in my project root which contains

```
DENO_AUTH_TOKENS=<myGithubToken>@raw.githubusercontent.com
```

I'm trying to import the file like this:

```
import {<aClass>} from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<pathToTheFile>/index.d.ts";
```

I've tried running `deno run --allow-env -L debug theFileWhichImportsFromGithub.ts` which gives the Module not found error.

I've also tried getting the file with Postman which worked, which tells me my auth token and file path is correct, but I am doing something wrong with Deno.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77440789/edit) the question to include a [mre]? Also, see [the comments at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286289/deno-import-modules-from-private-repo#comment132859227_75286289) and the [release notes for using `deno run --env`](https://deno.com/blog/v1.38#deno-run---env). Note that types are not evaluated by default when using the `run` command, and `.d.ts` files contain only type delcarations (not values).

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your import like that: `import {} from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user>/<repo>/<branch>/path/file.tsx'`
   (*Intentionally leave an empty import to avoid any error before finish the process*)
2. Delete `deno.lock` and run deno with `-r` flag **(only once)** to force a cache reload

   `deno run -r --allow-env -L debug theFileWhichImportsFromGithub.ts`